# Can multiple apps behind a reverse proxy be authenticated at the same time?

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-connect

I have one "main" app and one "secondary" app

I need to authenticate users against an identity provider that uses OpenID Connect for the two apps at a time (basic flow, one consent only)

My idea is to put a reverse proxy in front of my two apps so they share the same host name, with a virtual host for the secondary app.

Is there something that would prevent me from doing that? If I obtain an access token with the main app, will the token be taken in account when navigating to the second app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a reverse proxy that acts as a single OpenID Connect Relying Party towards the OpenID Connect Provider. The reverse proxy would forward requests to your two apps, not using different virtual hosts but rather using proxy primitives e.g. `ProxyPass` in Apache. You could deply [mod_auth_openidc](https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc) in an Apache webserver to facilitate this.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my thoughts, I noticed there was an equivalent of the Apache module for Nginx : https://github.com/zmartzone/lua-resty-openidc, by the same team. I'll come back when I have tried to implement this.